# Prove that a map is injective iff ...

Tags: functions, solution-verification, proof-explanation

So I came accross this question in the "Intro to metric and topological spaces" asking:
Show that a map $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ is injective iff $ A = f^{-1}(f(A)) $ for all $ A \subseteq X $.

My proof:
Suppose $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ is injective, then for any pairs $ x_1, x_2 \in A $, $ (x_1 \neq x_2) \iff (f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)) $. Let $ A = (x_1, x_2) $, so $ (x_1, x_2) = f^{-1}(f(x_1, x_2)) $. Thus, $ A = f^{-1}(f(A)) $.

Proof from the book:
Let $ f: X \rightarrow Y $. We know from Proposition 3.14 from the book that $ A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A)) $ for any $ A \subseteq X $. Suppose that $ f $ is injective and let $ x \in f^{-1}(f(A)) $. Then $ f(x) \in f(A) $ so $ f(x) = f(a) $ for any $ a \in A $. But $ f $ is injective so $ x = a $. This proves that $ f^{-1}(f(A)) \subseteq A $, and together these give $ A = f^{-1}(f(A)) $.

Now suppose that $ A = f^{-1}(f(A)) $ for any $ A \subseteq X $. For any $ x \in X $ take $ A = \{ x \} $ and we get $ {x} = f^{-1}(f(x)) $. This says that if $ f(x') = f(x) $ then $ x' = x $, that is, $ f $ is injective.

What I don't understand is the second part of the book's proof:

1. I know that the first part of the proof completes the double inclusion using Proposition 3.14, but isn't that already enough?
2. Is the second part a continuation of the first part?
3. In the second part, if $ A \subseteq X $ then it is possible that $ A = X $, so $ f(x') = f(x) $ does not directly imply that $ f $ is injective because it may be onto, no?

Also, if my proof correct?

Comment: The second part of the proof is for the 'if' part of the implication. In second part it is given that $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ for **every**  $A \subseteq X$.  If this holds only for $A=X$ then $f$ need not be injective.

Comment: Your proof is also missing some pieces. You proved, that if f is injective, every two Element Set fullfills $A=f^-1(f(A))$. No statement has been made for other Sets. You're missing the other direction of the implication as well, the steps you did take were correct however.

Comment: @watertrainer Thank you for your response. When I tried to prove the statement using all pairs of points, I was thinking that that would prove for all combination pairs (including pairs of only themselves). Therefore, that would cover for the other sets.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for your response. I just realised that you have to prove both implications in a biconditional statement...

Comment: The actual proof works similar, but what you've written now doesn't show how you want to generalize from 2 element sets to any possible subset (which doesn't work on this level of generalziation, A might be infinte)